# Slim framework is not working

Tags: php, slim

Currently I am using ubuntu and I would like to install `PHP Slim framework` in my system.

I have install composer through command line and also manually install Slim framework then I have created a index.php file in slim folder and put following code in that file and when I try to run that file does not see.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new SlimApp();
//slim application routes
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) { 
 $response->write("Welcome: This is AlphansoTech Tutorial Guide");
 return $response;
});
$app->run()
?>
```

I tried to call `http://localhost/slim/index.php`, showing me blank screen.

I don't know what happen first time i am installing and using slim framework.

I tried following url for installing slim framework.

http://www.alphansotech.com/blogs/php-restful-api-framework-slim-tutorial/

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/installation.html

How to install or run api using slim framework?

Comment: Have you check the installation guide? https://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/installation.html

Comment: You can check the slim-skeleton, it is a good choice for beginners. There the configurations etc should get clearer... https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton

Answer (score 1):

Slim can not find vendor folder which contains all Slim files and other dependencies required in your **composer.json**

You must install all dependencies first

Run This commend from your Project directory

```
composer install
```

Then Check your Routes Again. If you don't have the Composer visit getcomposer.org first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Slim code which I installed by using composer.

**index.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

My URL for accessing the file is `http://localhost/slim/index.php/hello/suresh`

Installation folder name - `slim`

**Output Received**

```
Hello, suresh
```

**Documentation followed from** - https://www.slimframework.com/

Hope, it'll give you some hint to solve your problem.

Comment: given me following error. Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

Comment: Don't u've any ```vendor``` folder?

Comment: ok, do one thing. Create one more folder. Inside that install ```slim``` by composer  using command ```composer require slim/slim```. Then create a file file called ```index.php``` with the code which I've given in top. After ```slim``` get installed you will able to see one ```vendor``` folder.

Comment: still slim is not installed i don't know how it could be installed ?

Comment: ./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143504/discussion-between-mi6crazyheart-and-samir).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the creation of the $app.
The way that works for me to create an application is:

```
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

$app = AppFactory::create();
```